# OpenGL - Explain glutInitDisplayMode()

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d, glut, glu

Explain in detail what functionality is provided by the settings in the line:

```
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DEPTH);
```

so far i know that this line will initialize the display mode by requesting a double buffere
setting, setting a RGBA window mode and request a depth buffer but how can i explain this more simply. i want to describe each argument in simple English

Comment: "i want to describe each argument in simple English " That *is* simple English. Complicated English would be explaining what exactly double-buffering, depth buffers, and having RGBA color components mean. Is that what you're asking for? Because that's not simple.

Comment: ok your wright maybe i wasn't clear with this question.. but thats what i need. can u help?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DEPTH);
```

`glutInitDisplayMode` - inits display mode

`GLUT_DOUBLE` - allows for display on the double buffer window

`GLUT_RGBA` - shows color (Red, green, blue) and an alpha

`GLUT_DEPTH` - allows for depth buffer

http://www.opengl.org/documentation/specs/glut/spec3/node12.html